# ajax success not working with 1.7.1

Tags: jquery

Recently i upgraded the jquery version from 1.2.6 to 1.7.1 and ajax call is not working.

It is not going inside success block.

If i revert the jquery version i.e 1.2.6 code works absolutely fine.

```
function getCompanyDetails(){

            var email = arguments[0].value;
            alert(email);
            validateForm(email);
            if(email)
                {  var args = arguments;
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/servlet/genericate?email=vis.gu%40mphasis.com",
                            dataType:'json',
                            success: function(data) {

                            alert(data);
                                if(data.companyName=='null')
                                {
                                    $("#"+""+args[2]+"").val("");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $("#"+""+args[2]+"").val(data.companyName);                     
                                }

                                if(data.address=='null')
                                {
                                    $("#"+""+args[3]+"").val("");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    $("#"+""+args[3]+"").val(data.address);
                                }

                    },
                            error: function() {
                            alert("Error");
                    }
                    });
                 }  
    }
```

Comment: Seems strange? There are way too many quotes in those selectors (not that it should matter), and why did'nt you just as well upgrade to the latest version of JQ ?

Comment: _"It is not going inside success block."_ - But is it going to the `error` block? Is the request getting to your servlet? And do any errors appear in your browser's JS console?

Comment: Try to remove comma after datatype replace it into dataType:'json'

Comment: at servlet level am getting null value

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace

```
success: function(data) {
              alert(data);
```

with

```
statusCode: {
    200: function(data) {
              alert(data);
```

I know this is not a perfect and best answer but atleast you can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to update your jQuery, you should update to the newest version. All of the notes about updating are [**HERE**](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed)

**Once you update, this is what jQuery has to say about making it backwards compatible:**

We realize that existing sites and plugins may be affected by these changes, and are providing the jQuery Migrate plugin for a transitional upgrade path. Individual descriptions below indicate if the behavior changed in 1.9 can be restored by using the jQuery Migrate plugin. Note that all of the changes in jQuery 1.9 will also apply to jQuery 2.0, and the jQuery Migrate plugin will be usable there as well.

The uncompressed development version of the jQuery Migrate plugin includes console log output to warn when specific deprecated and/or removed features are being used. This makes it valuable as a migration debugging tool for finding and remediating issues in existing jQuery code and plugins. It can be used for its diagnostics with versions of jQuery core all the way back to 1.6.4.

The compressed version of the plugin does not generate any log output, and can be used on production sites when jQuery 1.9 or higher is desired but older incompatible jQuery code or plugins must also be used. Ideally this would only be used as a short-term solution, but that's a decision for you to make.

Here is the link to the [**MIGRATE PLUGIN**](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/)